# Overriding the swagger 2 api-docs does not result in my controller being called possible because of PropertySourcedMapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, springfox

I am attempting to overrode the api-docs end point with my own controller, this doesn't seem to work.

I have set in application.properties

```
springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path=/somethingelse
```

I then made my own controller which has

```
@RequestMapping(
    value = "/v2/api-docs",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, "application/hal+json" })
```

This is an attempt to override the response given by the `Swagger2Controller` which looks like:

```
  @RequestMapping(
      value = DEFAULT_URL, // /v2/api-docs
      method = RequestMethod.GET,
      produces = { APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, HAL_MEDIA_TYPE })
  @PropertySourcedMapping(
      value = "${springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path}",
      propertyKey = "springfox.documentation.swagger.v2.path")
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<Json> getDocumentation(
      @RequestParam(value = "group", required = false) String swaggerGroup,
      HttpServletRequest servletRequest) {
```

For some reason the requests are still going to that controller and not my controller.

What is strange is that if my controller doesn't exist requests to `/v2/api-docs` wont respond.

spring fox : 2.9.2
spring: 5.1.4

Comment: I seemed to be able to override it by using `PropertySourcedMapping` in my controller and setting its properties to set the end point to /v2/api-docs

Answer (score -1):

class A extends **Swagger2DocumentationConfiguration**

**Override**

```
public HandlerMapping swagger2ControllerMapping(Environment environment, DocumentationCache documentationCache,
  ServiceModelToSwagger2Mapper mapper, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer) {
    return new PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping(
        environment,
        new CustomSwagger2Controller(environment, documentationCache, mapper, jsonSerializer));
}
```

**CustomSwagger2Controller** is my custom controller